# Regex match multiple date formats

Tags: regex, powershell

I am building a PowerShell script that should validate the parameter input where a date-string is passed.
The allowed strings should be in the following format:

- yyyy-MM-dd
- yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm
- yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm K
- "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"
- "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm K"

There is a bug in the solution that will push this script which adds double quotes around strings containing spaces. My script should be able to work with the bug present, but also be prepared for when the bug is fixed.

I currently have the following Regex expression which works. The problem I see though is that it is very long and thus complex to read/troubleshoot. I want to keep the checking of specific numbers (to prevent users passing a 13th month for example, or have 86 minutes in an hour).

Another solution would normally be to use a ValidateScript and just test if the date gets parsed correctly, yet since the validation of the parameter happens at the solution this isn't an option.

Are there ways to improve my expression?

```
((19|2[0-9])[0-9]{2}\-(0?[1-9]|1[012])\-(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\ (0?[1-9]|1[1-9]|2[0-4]):([0-5][0-9])\ (\+|\-)(1[012]|0?[1-9])\:[03]0)$|((19|2[0-9])[0-9]{2}\-(0?[1-9]|1[012])\-(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\ (0?[1-9]|1[1-9]|2[0-4]):([0-5][0-9])\ (\+|\-)(1[012]|0?[1-9]))$|(19|2[0-9])[0-9]{2}\-(0?[1-9]|1[012])\-(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\ (0?[1-9]|1[1-9]|2[0-4]):([0-5][0-9])$|((19|2[0-9])[0-9]{2}\-(0?[1-9]|1[012])\-(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]))$|\"((19|2[0-9])[0-9]{2}\-(0?[1-9]|1[012])\-(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\ (0?[1-9]|1[1-9]|2[0-4]):([0-5][0-9])\ (\+|\-)(1[012]|0?[1-9])\:[03]0)\"$|\"((19|2[0-9])[0-9]{2}\-(0?[1-9]|1[012])\-(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\ (0?[1-9]|1[1-9]|2[0-4]):([0-5][0-9])\ (\+|\-)(1[012]|0?[1-9]))\"$|\"(19|2[0-9])[0-9]{2}\-(0?[1-9]|1[012])\-(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\ (0?[1-9]|1[1-9]|2[0-4]):([0-5][0-9])\"$
```

I have looked into backreferencing, but I don't think that really would apply to my case. My knowledge of Regex is basic, so I have no idea where to go from here.

Comment: Trying to come up with One Regex To Rule Them All is usually not a very good idea - it's hard to read, and therefore hard to debug and maintain. The best thing you can do is split your code into 5 successive checks rather than 1 :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest using `[Datetime]::ParseExact()` for this - it accepts a list of format strings, so start by defining those:

```
$acceptedFormats = @(
  'yyyy-MM-dd'
  'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm'
  'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm K'
  '\"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm\"'
  '\"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm K\"'
) -as [string[]]
```

Now all you have to do is call `[datetime]::ParseExact()` with your input date string as the first argument:

```
[datetime]::ParseExact('2023-01-15 16:45 +02:00', $acceptedFormats, $null, [System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles]::None)
[datetime]::ParseExact('"2023-01-15 16:45"', $acceptedFormats, $null, [System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles]::None)
```

Comment: Thank you for your input @mathias. I went for the following solution:
* Used \d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} for the string validation in the solution calling the script for an early catch.
* Within the script I put your suggested solution into a ValidateScript for a still kinda early catch.

Answer (score 0):

How about the -as operator?  It will return nothing if it can't convert.

```
if ('1' -as 'datetime') { 'yes' } else { 'no' }

no


if ('1:00' -as 'datetime') { 'yes' } else { 'no' }

yes
```